# Command won't stop running

Tags: python, image, scikit-image, viewer

I have the following piece of code

```
import skimage.color
import skimage.io
import skimage.viewer
import skimage.filters

fname = "/Users/harryhat/Desktop/Code/Experimental/Frames/frame00055.png"

# read image
image = skimage.io.imread(fname, as_gray=True)

# display the image
viewer = skimage.viewer.ImageViewer(image)
viewer.show()
```

However when I run the code, firstly the command won't stop running and secondly when I interrupt the command I have to restart the kernel to be able to type in the console. I was wondering why this would be the case / any other ways to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The skimage viewer is a Qt application. To run these in a notebook, you need to enable the Qt event loop integration by typing `%gui qt` in its own cell at the start of the notebook.

Just by the way, the scikit-image viewer is going to be deprecated. I recommend trying out https://napari.org as an alternative. (But the advice above still applies!)